# Getting syntax error for json in PostgreSQL: could not identify an equality operator for type json

Tags: json, postgresql, function, postgresql-9.4

I wrote a retrieve function in PostgreSQL. In JSON calling another object and I am getting a duplicate value so I added a distinct and run could not identify an equality operator for type JSON.

Here is my function:

```
return query
    select(SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(resdt))) FROM 
            (select distinct  vp.project_id,cvv.id as projid,vp.project_name,vp.description,vp.start_date,vp.end_date,vp.duration,
             vp.label_id,vp.created_by,vp.company_id,vp.provider_name as client_name,vp.actual_end_date,
             concat(vu.first_name,vu.last_name) as user_name,
            --vt.name as company_name,vt.domain,
             vu.email,
             10 as chat_count,vp.project_start_time,vp.project_end_time,
             vp.status as project_status,
    (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(b))) FROM
         (select vpr.project_id,vpr.project_name,vl.label_id,vl.label_name,vl.label_type
           from public."VOfficeApp_projects" vpr
           inner join public."VOfficeApp_project_labels" vpl on vpr.project_id = vpl.project_id
           inner join  public."VOfficeApp_labels" vl on  vl.label_id = vpl.label_id
           where vpr.company_id = 1047
           and vpr.created_by = 3465
           and vpr.project_id = vp.project_id
           and vl.label_type ='p' )b)as label_name,
     (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(b))) FROM
         (select concat(u.first_name,u.last_name) as first_name,vpr.employee_id as id,
           vpr.project_resource_id,u.email
           from public."VOfficeApp_projects" pro 
           inner join public."VOfficeApp_project_resources" vpr on pro.project_id = vpr.project_id
           inner join public."VOfficeApp_user" u on  vpr.employee_id = u.id
           where pro.company_id = 1047
           and pro.created_by = 3465 and vpr.released_date is null
           and pro.project_id = vp.project_id)b)as team_members


         from public."VOfficeApp_projects" vp
                    inner join  public."VOfficeApp_project_resources" vpr on vp.project_id = vpr.project_id
                     inner join public."VOfficeApp_user" vu on vu.id =vpr.employee_id
                    left join public."VOfficeApp_conversation" cvv on cvv.projtaskid = vp.project_id
                     where vp.company_id = 1047 and vpr.employee_id = 3465
                    and  vp.status != 'Delete'    
                    --order by vp.project_id desc
    )resdt)as My_tasks;
```

Comment: Use `jsonb` instead

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.